# Hosting WIF Identity Provider and generating self signed certificates for it

Tags: asp.net, azure-web-app-service, x509certificate, wif, claims-based-identity

For my final year project I've developed an ASP.NET website and I've implemented a Single Sign On Login System using Windows Identity Foundation (in a similar manner to the tutorial shown here: http://www.primaryobjects.com/2013/08/08/using-single-sign-on-with-windows-identity-foundation-in-mvc-net )

This means that I currently have a 2 Websites, my Identity Provider Site and the site that uses the IP and contains most of the functionality.The IP uses X509 certificate to generate the token and for this I've been able  so far to use a self signed certificate. This is the code that I've been using to retrieve the certificate from the local machine:

```
 var store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
        X509Certificate2Collection certificates = null;
        store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);

        try
        {
            certificates = store.Certificates;
            var certs = certificates.OfType<X509Certificate2>().Where(x => x.SubjectName.Name.Equals(subjectName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)).ToList();

            if (certs.Count == 0)
                throw new ApplicationException(string.Format("No certificate was found for subject Name {0}", subjectName));
            else if (certs.Count > 1)
                throw new ApplicationException(string.Format("There are multiple certificates for subject Name {0}", subjectName));

            return new X509Certificate2(certs[0]);
        }
```

In order to be able to present my project I will be asked to host it on the web, but this will mean that I'll need a substitute for my self signed certificate.

I could use something like azure websites to host my websites but I wasn't able to find a solution so far that would allow me to generate a self signed certificate on a service like azure and retrieve it programatically.

Could you please suggest me a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you wouldn't have to create your own IDP. You could use something like ADFS.

Azure AD is an IDP and has its own certificates so you don't need to create any.

All you need is the metadata and you can find the URL under AppServices / Endpoints.

There's an example [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-wsfederation/) but note that this uses WS-Fed OWIN not WIF. (WIF is somewhat old school).

To make your life easier, you can update your web.config [programmatically](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-signing-key-rollover) by adding code to global.asax.

Or just move your whole solution to a VM in Azure.

Comment: Yea I get your point and I agree, on a real-world project I wouldn't waste time by building a provider myself.  I saw this as an opportunity to understand this concept in-depth and add a twist to a part of the application that normally nobody would pay any attention to. Anyway, thanks for the suggestion. Ill give those Azure VMs a look.